# ansible create string from variable comma separted

Tags: ansible

I have this variable:

```
amq_ping_hosts:
  - "10.1.1.1"
  - "10.1.1.2"
  - "10.1.1.3"
  - "10.1.1.4"
```

and I want to create variable with a comma separated string:

ping_hosts: 10.1.1.1,10.1.1.2,10.1.1.3.10.1.1.4

I tried this:

```
- name: "set fact ping_hosts"
  set_fact:
    ping_hosts: "{{ ping_hosts }} ',' {{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ amq_ping_hosts }}"
```

but ping_hosts is an undefined variable

Comment: `ping_hosts: "{{ ping_hosts | default('') }} ',' {{ item }}"`

Comment: There is a problem with the comma in the first iteration. *ping_hosts: ',10.1.1.1,10.1.1.2,10.1.1.3,10.1.1.4'*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [*join*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#join). The tasks below

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        ping_hosts: "{{ amq_ping_hosts|join(',') }}"
    - debug:
        var: ping_hosts
```

give

```yaml
  ping_hosts: 10.1.1.1,10.1.1.2,10.1.1.3,10.1.1.4
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `join` function from python:

```
  tasks:
  - set_fact: 
      ping_hosts: "{{ ','.join(amq_ping_hosts) }}"

  - debug:
      var: ping_hosts
```